# Aggregate nearby points to develop equally sized regions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, point-in-polygon, vector-grid

I have a list of 4,500 points (lat, long, unique id, attribute). I also have a service territory which all of the points fall into. I would like to break the service territory (polygon) into 6 contiguous regions containing an equal number of points (each region should be a single polygon containing 750 points).

Is there a quick, efficient way to do this in QGIS?